# Couchbase server connection is giving an authentication error

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api, spark-framework

All I want to do is to do an upsert operation. I have a JsonDocument and I have a Couchbase server "123.456.789.1011" and a bucket inside, called "testbucket". Now, when I open the server using the IP address with port 8091, it asks me for a username and password say "uname","pwd" and, after entering, it opens. There is no any password for my bucket.

```
cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("123.456.789.101");
    cluster.clusterManager("testuser","testuser123");
    bucket = cluster.openBucket("testbucket");

    jsonObject = JsonObject.create()
            .put("Order",map);

    jsonDocument = JsonDocument.create("Hello",jsonObject);
    jsonDocumentResponse = bucket.upsert(jsonDocument);
```

This is my code, but the problem is always on running the code I get an error saying that

```
 ERROR spark.webserver.MatcherFilter -
```

com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "testbucket" do not match.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$1.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:156)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$1.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:146)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onError(OperatorMap.java:49)
    at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:177)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.access$000(OperatorObserveOn.java:65)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:153)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am new to Couchbase, and I really don;t know what to do. I Googled it but nothing is there on the web. Even their documentation is also not suggesting me anything. I hope someone on StackOverflow will surely have an answer for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you need to pass a bucket password(which is different than the cluster password) in the openBucket method: http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/com/couchbase/client/java/Cluster.html#openBucket%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I don't have a bucket password. It's null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to connect a bucket using the cluster credentials. Try instead connect to a bucket with bucket username and an empty password:

```
cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("123.456.789.101");
bucket = cluster.openBucket("testbucket", "");
```